# Problems with installing platform api (symfony 4.4, php 8)

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a problem with installing api platforms on symfony 4.4 (php version 8).

Using the command:

```
composer require api
```

I am getting such errors:
[image]

edit: @hakre i would like to use symfony 4.4 and php 8, which platform api version should I use?
My composer.json source:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-imagick": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
        "ext-redis": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "asm89/twig-cache-extension": "^1.4",
        "cocur/slugify": "^3.2",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.5",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.2",
        "diegosm/keycloak-admin": "1.5.7",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "emanueleminotto/twig-cache-bundle": "^1.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12",
        "google/apiclient-services": "^0.234.0",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "3.1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.4",
        "knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^2.7",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "3.4",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "4.3.4",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.14",
        "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^3.5",
        "setasign/fpdf": "^1.8",
        "setasign/fpdi": "^2.3.6",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.89.1",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.15.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.35.0",
        "sonata-project/exporter": "2.7",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^4.1",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.30.0",
        "sonata-project/news-bundle": "^3.17",
        "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^3.11.0",
        "sonata-project/page-bundle": "3.26.0",
        "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.10",
        "sonata-project/timeline-bundle": "^3.5",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.11",
        "stephpy/timeline-bundle": "^3.1",
        "stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak": "^2.2",
        "symfony/acl-bundle": "1.0.1",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/lock": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.5.0",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "^1.24",
        "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/ux-swup": "^1.2",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode": "^1.15"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "dama/doctrine-test-bundle": "^6.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.13",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.4",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "setasign\\FpdiPdfParser\\": "lib/FPDI_PDF-Parser-2.0.6/src/",
            "": "src/",
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "pre-autoload-dump": [
            "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        },
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "YouTube"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried also use params --ignore-platform-reqs and i have errors:

```
 Service "api_platform.error_listener": Parent definition "exception_listene  
!!    r" does not exist.
```

[image]

Comment: This depends on your requirements. If you know which PHP version etc., I'd specify the PHP platform first in the composer.json project configuration and then try again. To improve your question you should share your composer.json as otherwise not really much can be said on Stackoverflow - why not [edit] it in?

Comment: If you `"php": "^8.0"`  and the dependencies do not resolve for that version, then be lucky you know. Consult dependencie vendors for your PHP version support requirements and negotiate your options. Alternatively get support for (potentially outdated) PHP versions that are compatible with the dependencies. PHP 7.4 should still have community support for security fixes, but I don't think for long.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by installing api platform command:

```
 composer require api --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and then fixing the error:

```
Service "api_platform.error_listener": Parent definition "exception_listen
!! r" does not exist.
```

Adding to services.yaml:

```
api_platform.error_listener:
 class: ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\ErrorListener
 arguments:
   $controller: "@api_platform.action.exception"
   $logger: "@logger"
   $debug: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Comment: That can lead to even more problems in runtime. PHP 8 can be incompatible with your api platform version and throw errors/warnigns

Comment: If you have PHP 8 in your (PHP) platform (that is the runtime environment, not api-platform package), see [_`platform`_ (Composer Config)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) on how to configure it. If PHP 8 is causing you issues, use a lower PHP version in platform so that composer knows (and you have this documented). I think this is also what Justinas' comment reminds on, specify the dependencies and include the PHP platform so that you don't get surprises.